# How to stream a video on a simple selfmade Website, while recording the video?

Tags: video-streaming

i want to make a project where i can stream a input source, like a camera. That should run on a Raspberry pi. Users can open a website, where they can see the video, but most importantly can go back to different(older) timestamps of the video.
The Raspberry Pi should host that website.
Can you give me any hints how to realise that, or what i have to search for that?

It should work like the twitch video.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can use ffmpeg to capture the video from a source and encode it with certain parameters. You can use RTMP to transfer (ingest) the stream to a server as it gets encoded. Video segments should be transferred to a directory in your server, given you have opened the RTMP port to outside. You can use a web server such as Nginx on server to serve these and a media player (client) such as hls.js or DASH player on frontend. Years ago, I tried it out and documented in this repo but it's not up to date and I am not able to recall all details: https://github.com/yigiterinc/video-streaming-over-http